# Iphone 5 IMO messenger not working

Tags: iphone, ios

I have been using IMO messenger on my iPhone 5. 3 days ago imo was not working. I delete app and re-install it but the result is I can't get past the screen where I have to enter my mobile number and country. Still the page is in loading but I have not been able to complete the installation. Can anyone have a solution for this problem?

Comment: Checking latest version release dates, I found that iOS 8.3 had been released around that time. Did you update your iPhone about two weeks ago? The messenger itself received an update on April 17, did you install that latest version (through iTunes or on the phone directly) or an earlier version through iTunes. Have you asked the developers to see if this is a known issue they work on?